# Replacement for fnk3070pa

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet

I have a JR1738RX-12V remote control system in my child 4WD car. We noticed that it's too slow/weak so we decided to put 4xRS-570 motors to give it more juice but they are 65W compared 45W from original ones.

Car is barely moving now and the culprit in my (newbie) option are the mosfets inside of the unit. Two of them are fnk3070pa (http://www.fnk-tech.com/comp/file/download.do?id=375) and can generate max 50W, while other two are http://www.chinesechip.com/chipFile/2015-07/100N03-18026-0.pdf and they can go up to 180W. My idea is to just try to replace these with the ones that can produce more power like this one https://docs.rs-online.com/f35b/0900766b812cf73f.pdf

Is this a good enough replacement? Am I missing something big?

Battery used:
https://greencell.global/en/other/1108-green-cell-battery-agm-12v-20ah.html

--- EDIT ---
Motors now: RS570 65W 40k rpm, before RS390 45W 15k rpm (https://www.dhgate.com/product/children-s-electric-car-dc-motor-kid-s-ride/496410887.html#redirect_detail=WAP2PC) cannot find more details about the engines themselves.

Even tho I messed up and taken the "high speed" motors which in reality give less torque which I actually wanted they should still be improvement from current setup.

Currently car (https://leantoys.com/product-eng-2824-Jeep-XJL-588-Electric-Ride-On-The-Car-White.html) with 4 of these barely starts moving then shuts down after 1 meter of driving. After cca 15sec you can hear the relay that turns it back on. We suspect it's the fuse that's protecting the plus wire on the battery.

Original battery on the car was replaced with this one. Original one was 10Ah max 2Amps while this one is 20Ah max 6Amps.

[image: PIC1] [image: PIC2]

[image: PIC3] [image: PIC4 - schema high level]

Comment: Schematic required plus technical details of the battery.

Comment: @Andyaka added a high level one and battery info, don't have the schema of the JR1738RX internals.

Comment: What are the specified voltages for the old and new motors. That is more likely to be area of relevance. Both FETs look OK for the likely task.

Comment: WARNING:  The FNK307A is a P Channel FET. The 100N03 is an N Channel FET - they should not need changing BUT if you did you would need to match P for P and N for N. .

Comment: What are the speed constants of the old and new motors? If Kv increased , Kt will have decreased giving less torque per amp, and you may be stalling the new motors.

Comment: Added more details about the motors and the car itself.

Comment: A web search indicates that the motors come in a range of speed versions. Replacement needs to be with a motor with similar speed rating. Replacing a low speed motor with a higher speed  one will have it trying to go faster at a given setting and being loadd down below its power band. || Specs of sorts can be deduced from various websites: [Goodish]( RS570 65W, before RS390 45W) and note [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32918963734.html) widely differing speeds for same motor model,   ...

Comment: [Search fodder](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALeKk01-T6gy6Sk6Xyg8pOmA50_ICfiKcQ%3A1597537121348&ei=YXs4X_fdFMf6z7sPvoCjoAw&q=%22RS570%22+%22RS390%22&oq=%22RS570%22+%22RS390%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQRzoECCMQJ1DukAhYlfsIYPOeCWgAcAF4AIAB1AGIAaQMkgEFMC43LjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi3kojFuZ7rAhVH_XMBHT7ACMQQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yes true, I've bought rs570 40krpm and original one was rs390 15krpm.  I've tried connecting rs570 directly to the battery and it runs like crazy, couldn't stop it with my hand. While when it's going via the control unit it can barely start.

Comment: @Reeebuuk Those FETs should run the motors at full power with minimal power loss IF they are properly driven and the controller is not faulty.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Controller worked fine before the change of motors and battery is brand new so don't know what to do here...